# Camera not recording at 720p 60fps

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

I have this code to open a camera and display it on a `Image` on C# WPF.

```
public async void initializeCamara(int index, int fps, System.Drawing.Size resolution)
        {
            
            videoCapture = new VideoCapture(index, VideoCaptureAPIs.DSHOW);
            videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.Fps, this.fps);
            videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameHeight, this.resolution.Height);
            videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameWidth, this.resolution.Width);

            await Task.Run(() => displayCameraCallback());
        }
```

Then I take the current frame from the image and save it with a `VideoWriter`.

It works fine except when I use a resolution of 720p and a framerate of 60 fps, in this case the video recorded is shorter than it should (less than half duration).

(60 fps and another resolution works fine and 720p and 30 fps also)

(I'm using aforge to get the fps and resolution available)

Any help? Thanks

Comment: What interface are you using? Just a stab in the dark, but the datarate for 750p and 60FPS is relatively close to the maximum of what USB2 can handle, not counting any possible overhead. ~442MBit/s just for image data if you use an 8bit pixel format of the 480MBit/s of USB2.

Comment: Check the installed driver.  It is best to use the manufacturer driver of camera than the generic Microsoft Driver.  Generic drivers do not always work!!!